# Regex search keyword in parentheses

Tags: c#, sql, regex

I want to search keyword GROUP BY in parentheses.

This is my regex pattern:

```
(?i)(\s+|^)\(\s*((.|\n)*)GROUP\s+BY\s+((.|\n)*)\s*\)
```

But, it matches all digit in case (..GROUP BY..) in another parentheses.

Examples, this is text pattern:

```
(SELECT Col1 FROM Table_Name A WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE Col1>0 GROUP BY Col1)

(SELECT  column1, column2
FROM Table_name1)

 INNER JOIN (                                            
 SELECT column1, column2
 FROM   Table_name2     
 WHERE  column1 > 0                                                      
 GROUP BY column1, column2   
 ) AS TN
```

I want to matches  `(SELECT column1, column2 FROM Table_name2 WHERE  column1 > 0 GROUP BY column1, column2 )`. But it matches all.

Answer (score 1):

If we wouldn't have nested queries/parentheses, I'm guessing that this simple expression with an `i` flag might work:

```
(\([^)]*?\bgroup\b\s+\bby\b[^)]*?\))
```

and we might be able to even more simplify that. Otherwise, it would be pretty complicated to design an expression for.

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/7JWvwA/1/), if you wish to explore further or modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/7JWvwA/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

---

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(\([^)]*?\bgroup\b\s+\bby\b[^)]*?\))";
        string input = @"(SELECT  column1, column2
FROM Table_name1)

 INNER JOIN (                                            
 SELECT column1, column2
 FROM   Table_name2     
 WHERE  column1 > 0                                                      
 GROUP BY column1, column2   
 ) AS TN

(SELECT  column1, column2
FROM Table_name1)

 INNER JOIN (                                            
 SELECT column1, column2
 FROM   Table_name2     
 WHERE  column1 > 0                                                      
 GROUP BY column1, column2   
 ) AS TN";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline;
        
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I try run your regex with text pattern. (SELECT Col1 FROM Table_Name A WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE Col1>0 GROUP BY Col1). It fail. I guess the cause is by NOLOCK in parentheses

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it with the simplest version:

```
\([^(]*GROUP BY[^)]*\)
```

This extracts exactly what you're looking for; i.e. The sub-query with the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @downvoter: Specifying a reason would help immensely!